# How to display horizontal scroll bar with seeing the data?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I have large amount of data in table.Every time need to scroll down of the page and using the scroll bar need to see the data.

I need an horizontal scroll bar with what am i seeing in the screen .

using this every no need to go down and scroll the page.

Thanks your help.

Comment: can u show your code

Answer (score 0):

Without code, the best answer I can give you is

```
overflow-y: visible
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the table in a div

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="tablesorter">
    <!-- ... -->
  </table>
</div>
```

then set the css as follows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/98/)):

```
.wrapper {
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Comment: This only adds a scrollbar to the BOTTOM of the table, thus having to vertically scroll down - if the table has a lot of rows - before able to scroll horizontally. IMHO that was the original problem (and the one I'm facing now). @Mottie is there an option to add a horizontal scroll bar to the top?